# Google drive .zip file set permission expiration

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-client

Is it possible to set an expiration time for a permission on a non-google drive file? e.g. a zip file (*not* a google doc, spreadsheet, .etc.).

If so, how does one do it?

I am using the following function to generate a shareable link:

```
public function getShareableLink($file) {
    $tempPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission([
        'type' => 'anyone',
        'role' => 'reader',
        'withLink' => true,
    ]);
    $this->service->permissions->create($file, $tempPermission);
    $fileMetadata = $this->service->files->get($file, array('fields' => 'webViewLink'));
    return $fileMetadata->getWebViewLink();
}
```

and it seems I can set an expiration via the permission class, however I can't find any information in the drive gui as to whether the link expires (or even to set an expiry time for that matter).

Comment: Permissions of Drive API has the property of `expirationTime`. But in the current stage, `expirationTime` cannot be used. This might be a bug. This situation has already been reported to the issue tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760655 As a workaround for using `expirationTime`, I achieve by using Web Apps of Google Apps Script as an API. I give the expiration time by installing a time-driven trigger with the Web Apps. I commented this because I'm not sure whether this is the direction you want. If this is not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike yea not quite the direction I'd go in, but nevertheless appreciate the useful link. you think a company like google could get their api and documentation together. i've never seen worse documentation in my life, where half of the code examples are out of date wrt the current api version and I have to actively search for things that should be easily available. the entire request I am trying to make is easily done in one line with dropbox, and about 5 lines with aws.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I deeply apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: no need to apologize ;) like i said, appreciate the input.

Comment: Thank you. If you need a sample script, feel free to tell me. Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that it is required to use workarounds for achieving `expirationTime` of the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

so far, the expiry option is open to permission type of 'user' only.